# HTML table download to Excel and add images

Tags: javascript, excel, image, html-table, download

I'm trying to use this script to save a html table to Excel file and add images in the end.
I use this code:

```
function tableToExcel(element) {
        var html, link, blob, url;

        html = element.innerHTML;
        blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
            type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
        });
        url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link = document.createElement('A');
        link.href = url;
        link.download = 'Отчёт';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, 'Document.xlsx'); // IE10-11
        else link.click();  // other browsers
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    };
```

But get this result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Wum.png)

My html code:

```
<div class="WordSection1">
        <table id="result_table">
            ...............
        </table>
        <div>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ graph.0 }}" alt="Matplotlib Graph">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ graph.1 }}" alt="Matplotlib Graph">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ graph.2 }}" alt="Matplotlib Graph">
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ graph.3 }}" alt="Matplotlib Graph">
        </div>
</div>
```

Adding images in base64, so probably, problem in this?
And how to solve it?